# How to make multi-subscriber modelling like Twitch,OnlyFans

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, revenuecat, google-play-billing

I want to make dynamic multi-subscribing modeling like Twitch, Onlyfans. For example, my customer can subscribe user1 feed also user2 feed but user1 and user2 is not static, it's dynamic.

How can I achieve this in RevenueCat? Is subscribing API allow that? How Twitch achieved this?